# What is a Normal [1,1] distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

In my textbook I'm given the following question, "An investor is contemplating an investment with a return of £ R , where: R = 250,000 - 100,000N, and N is a Normal [1,1] random variable" (part a,b,c follow from there). What does this Normal [1,1] random variable mean? Is [1,1] just the mean and variance of a Normal distribution? The answer begins, "N has a Normal [1,1] distribution, so R has a Normal distribution with mean 150,000 and variance
100,000 , ie R~N(150,000, 100,000^2)". How and why is this done?

Thanks !

Comment: "R has a Normal distribution with mean 150,000 and variance 100,000 , ie R~N(150,000, 100,000)" seems to be a direct answer to the titular question. We can infer that a N[a,b] distribution has mean a and variance b. The remaining portion depends on knowing about the linear transformations of expectation and variance. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Are you sure it didn't say, "R has a Normal distribution with mean 150,000 and **standard deviation** 100,000, so $R\sim N(150,000, 100,000)".$ So that the second argument of $N$ is the standard deviation, not the variance? // If $X$ has $E(X) = \mu$ and $Var(X) = \sigma^2,$ and $Y = aX+b,$ for $a>0, b> 0,$ then $E(Y) = a\mu +b,$ $Var(Y)=a^2\sigma^2.$ and $SD(Y) = a\sigma.$

Comment: If you have correctly transcribed all the details, the answer given in your question has an error (at least one).

Comment: I've seen different people (and even the same people) mix the notation $N(\mu, \sigma)$ and the notation $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Positively, which is being used is clear if symbols are explained. It may or may not help to underline that $N(1, 1)$ is an example that doesn't allow a guess at which is being used, as manifestly SD of 1 and variance of 1 imply each other.

Answer (score 1):

I am showing details of a similar example because I think there is
a mistake in the statement of your problem. The general formulas
in the next paragraph are true for any distribution with mean $\mu$
and standard deviation $\sigma$--not just normal distributions.

If $X$ has $E(X) = \mu$ and $Var(X) = \sigma^2,$ and $Y = aX+b,$ for $a>0, b> 0,$ then $E(Y) = a\mu +b,$ $Var(Y)=a^2\sigma^2.$ and $SD(Y) = a\sigma.$

Demonstration by simulation (in R): With a (normal) sample of a million, sample means and standard
deviations should match corresponding population expectations and standard deviations to about one decimal place. (Variances have squared units and so accuracy may be limited to a few significant digits.)

```
set.seed(2021)
x = rnorm(10^6, 100, 15)   # normal sample of one million
mean(x);  var(x);  sd(x)
[1] 100.0071   # aprx E(X) = 100
[1] 225.5395   # aprx Var(X) = 225
[1] 15.01797   # aprx SD(X) = 15

y = 2*x + 5
mean(y);  var(y);  sd(y)
[1] 205.0143   # aprx E(Y) = 2(100) + 5 = 205
[1] 902.1579   # aprx Var(Y) = 4(225) = 900
[1] 30.03594   # aprx SD(Y) = 2(15) = 30
```

The figure below shows histograms (blue) for samples along with the
corresponding population density functions (red).

[image]

R code for figure:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
 hist(x, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main="NORM(100, 15)")
  curve(dnorm(x, 100, 15), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
 hist(y, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main="NORM(105, 30)") 
  curve(dnorm(x, 205, 30), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```